# Access to div from codebehind who's outside a repeater Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, code-behind, htmlgenericcontrol

I know its maybe unusual, but i want add htmlGenericControl to a div (it's outside a repeater) in ItemDataBound from CodeBehind..

```
HtmlGenericControl slider = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("slider");

htmlGenericControl input = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
input.Attributes.Add("type", "radio");
input.Attributes.Add("name", "slide_switch");
input.Attributes.Add("id", string.Format("projectImage-{0}", item.ProjectImageId));

slider.Controls.Add(input);
```

but its return ***null*** everytime. this is the aspx code:

```
  <div class="slider">
      <asp:Repeater ID="rptProjectImages" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptProjectImages_ItemDataBound">

           <ItemTemplate>
           </ItemTemplate>

       </asp:Repeater>
   </div>
```

Comment: if it's outside the repeater, you shouldn't need to `FindControl`, it should just be a protected member accessible from your codebehind as `slider.Controls.Add` - I don't know if this will fix your issue, but in case it helps.  Oh, you do need runat=server and an id for the slider though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues with this code.

First, your div is client-side only, from server-side point of view it's just a string. Turn it into server-side control with:

```
<div class="slider" runat="server" ID="slider">
```

Second, `FindControl` looks for immediate children only, in your case children of the repeater item. `slider` is not one of those. Moreover, it is not a part of the repeater item template and should be accessible as in in code behind, so just

```
slider.Controls.Add(...
```

That is unless `slider` and the repeater you showed are a part of some other template of some "outer" control. In which case make sure to use that "outer" control to call `FindControl` on.

Finally, don't mess with `id`. I bet this is either going to be overridden by ASP.NET, or will cause issues on the page. Instead set client ID mode to static and assign ID property:

```
input.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
input.ID = string.Format("projectImage_{0}", item.ProjectImageId);
```

This is eventually output the same value for `id` you needed, but in more ASP.NET compliant way. One note though is that I replaced "-" with "_" - server side controls cannot have hyphens in ID

Comment: I stay away from static client id mode.  There is no reason to use it and it is known to cause problems with update panels at the very least.  And I am not sure why you are assuming that he is trying to find slider within the repeater.  "e" must be the parent control of the "slider" div, but maybe I am wrong in assuming that.

Comment: @AgapwIesu, I am assuming so because it fits naturally to the code provided, that's it. I don't use static IDs much, but this was the first thing that came to mind to help OP have id exactly as desired.

Comment: @Andrei Thanks, server side controls cannot have hyphens or should not have?

Comment: @MortezaAghili, cannot, it will cause parsing error in ASP.NET

Answer (score 2):

Didnt work with asp.net too long, but probably this should help

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server">...</div>
```

and in codebehind `myDiv`  should be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

FindControl finds a control within another, but does so looking for the control's id.  Your "slider" control has no id, it uses a class named "slider" but has no id.

You will need to define the control as

```
<div runat="server" id="Slider" class="slider">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptProjectImages" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptProjectImages_ItemDataBound">

         <ItemTemplate>
         </ItemTemplate>

     </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

The `runat="server"` tells the framework to instantiate that control in your code behind.  The id will be the name of the object that is that control.  Then in your code, you can do

```
htmlGenericControl input = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
input.Attributes.Add("type", "radio");
input.Attributes.Add("name", "slide_switch");
input.ID = string.Format("projectImage-{0}", item.ProjectImageId);

Slider.Controls.Add(input);
```